# Bootstrap 4 expandable card header has spacing & wrapping issues and rotating icon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on creating a bootstrap4 card with a title/body and close button that can expand and collapse. I have been following this tutorial:
[Card collapse tricks!](https://disjfa.github.io/bootstrap-tricks/card-collapse-tricks/)

I like the example but want to do two things:

- move expand icon to left of card-header
- add close button to right of card-header

In this jsfiddle I have attempted to do these two things:

https://jsfiddle.net/s0ygr35L/1/

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

my attempt:

<div class="card ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
    <h5 class="card-header expandable">

        <!-- method2 -->
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-example" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example" id="heading-example" class="d-block">
            <div class="row " style='margin-bottom:0;'>
                
                <div class="col-md-1 ">
                    <i class="rotate fa fa-chevron-down "></i>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col">
                    <p>Collapsible Group Item #1</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col">
                    <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
                </div>
             
            </div>
        </a>
         
        
    </h5>
    <div id="collapse-example" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
        <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon
            officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3
            wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
            Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan
            excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
            you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



example:


<div class="card ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
    <h5 class="card-header expandable">
        <!-- method1  -->
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-example2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example" id="heading-example" class="d-block">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
            Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
        
        
    </h5>
    <div id="collapse-example2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
        <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon
            officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3
            wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
            Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan
            excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
            you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first card is my attempt, I added a col / row section for the header, but this has resulted in some unwanted blank space at the bottom?
[image]

I tried setting the style to have padding-bottom=0 and margin-bottom=0 but it didn't fix it.
The close button on the right of the card-title is also rotating whenever the card is expanded/collapsed, because of the css code. I tried making the css identifier more specific but it keeps rotating the icon?

Can anyone help me:

- remove the blank space at the bottom of my card-title
- prevent my close icon button from rotating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are adding extra elements into the card header. You don't need to add a grid for the header, expander and close icons - you are already using Bootstrap classes to tell it where to place them. This grid is what is adding the space you were talking about, as well as breaking the layout on small screens.

This is all you need for your header:

```
<h5 class="card-header expandable">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-example" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example" id="heading-example" class="d-block">
        <i class="rotate fa fa-chevron-down "></i>
         Collapsible Group Item #1
        <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
    </a>
</h5>
```

For the rotating close icon, the problem is that the code you have to rotate the expander icon is also getting applied to your close icon. You can add the `rotate` class to your CSS so that it gets applied only to classes that have that class added:

```
.expandable .collapsed .rotate.fa{
      transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

You can see it all working below:

```css
.expandable .fa {
      transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
    }
.expandable .collapsed .rotate.fa{
      transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="card ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
    <h5 class="card-header expandable">

        <!-- method2 -->
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-example" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example" id="heading-example" class="d-block">
                    <i class="rotate fa fa-chevron-down "></i>
                     Collapsible Group Item #1
                    <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
        </a>
         
        
    </h5>
    <div id="collapse-example" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
        <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon
            officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3
            wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
            Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan
            excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
            you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @martin, did this work for you or do you need more help to resolve the question?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add flex property and wrap all 3 element inside it, see below.

```css
.expandable .fa {
      transition: 0.3s transform ease-in-out;
      display: flex;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .expandable .collapsed .fa{
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    .card-header .d-flex{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    } 
    .card-header p{
      display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<div class="card ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
    <h5 class="card-header expandable">
        <!-- method1 
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-example" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example" id="heading-example" class="d-block">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
            Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a> -->
        
        <!-- method2 -->
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-example" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-example" id="heading-example" class="d-block">
            <div class="row " style='margin-bottom:0;'>
                
                <!-- <div class="col-md-1 ">
                    
                </div> -->
                
                <div class="col d-flex ">
                   <div class="d-flex">
                      <i class="rotate fa fa-chevron-down "></i>
                      <p class="mb-0">Collapsible Group Item #1</p>
                   </div>
                  <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
                </div>
                
                <!-- <div class="col">
                    <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
                </div> -->
             
            </div>
        </a>
         
        
    </h5>
    <div id="collapse-example" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading-example">
        <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon
            officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3
            wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
            Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan
            excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
            you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also check in [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_Panwar/ska9zhb3/21/)